# Infinite 'for' loop with Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I have a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..xx};do break="$i"
If....; then Some command
else break;fi
done
```

I need something which can repeat this script n times with incrementing $i.

I tried this:

```
For (( ; ; )); do  i=1 && echo $i && ((i++));done
```

But this always shows 1, not an incrementing number. I also tried `$((i+=1))`.

Where `xx` is must be endless number.

Where `break="$i"` gives me how many times repeated script.

Comment: `while true; do ((i++)); echo $i; done`

Comment: `{1..xx}` isn't valid, you want `$(seq 1 $xx)` or similar. Your attempt at an infinite loop is ok, but your problem is that you're setting `i=1` every time, so it gets set to 1, printed, increased, then set to 1 again... As @Cyrus suggets, a `while` loop is better. Also realise that `break="$i"` has no special meaning - `break` is just treated as a variable in this context.

Comment: @cyrus i=1 && cyrus's command works...  Thanks

Comment: @qualia I know that the `xx` is invalid but it is a number. I don't know how many times it will be repeated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `for` to create an endless loop is unidiomatic, but not hard. Just make the ending condition never true; or, trivially, omit it.

```
for((i=0; ;++i)); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The above is Bash only. The usual solution, which works in POSIX `sh` too, is to use `while true` (but then that doesn't come with an incrementing index, if that's really what you need).

Comment: It always repeats as `0` do yo have any idea

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (click the big checkmark from hollow to green) so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: sorry I am new on here. Thanks for your reply. I want to vote up but I need more reputations.